# Do I need initiation to say a beeja/bija mantra?

Tags: durga

1. I wanted to know if I can say the Durga bija mantra “duṃ”
2. Can I say this mantra while getting the full effects of the mantra without initiation?

   > “oṃ duṃ durgāyai nama:”

Comment: Just chanting "durgāyai nama:" should be fine.

Comment: full effect is only realized through initiation.

Comment: Ideally better to have but if you are using only one beeja. You can do it nishkaama. I.e just for the grace.

Comment: No initiation is needed. A guru might help in the pronunciation other than that you're fine.

Comment: @sv. Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same thing to my acharya . She told me that initiation transfers the strength the vital energy into your body . After which more you practice more you cultivate the same energy in to your body and mind  . If you call the beej akshara then you are simply calling her for satisfaction but will not lead to her vision .